# Moment js split time string

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Am using moment `JS` to get the current time. Based on that time I need execute search operation in my elastic search database.

My database entry is like this way :

```
"message_date": "2014-03-20T09:17:40.482Z"
```

Moment code to get current time is like this way :

```
var m = moment();
var testResult = m.toJSON();

// It outputs : 2014-03-20T09:17:40.482Z
```

My problem is I don't want to include that seconds filed in my database query. I want to search only up to minute field i.e **2014-03-20T09:17**. I can split the moment date to get the expected format. But i know its not the way to do that. Please help me to get the expected time format in moment `JS` way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var testResult = m.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm');
```

If you want to get the time in a particular timezone:

```
var m = moment().zone("+05:30");
var testResult = m.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm');
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Now am getting the date in local time. I need to convert it to + 5.30 added format (IND).
tried this one get undefined value 
console.log('test 2', testResult2.toJSON);